# Is assigning to a union member from a different member in the same union defined by the C standard?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider:

```
union { int i; char c; } x = {0};
x.c = x.i;
```

C 2018 6.15.16.1 3, about simple assignment, says:

> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

`x.c` and `x.i` overlap but not exactly and  do not have versions of a compatible type. So is the behavior of this assignment not defined by the C standard?

Comment: It's also worth considering things like `x.c = 0 + x.i;` and `x.c = (char)x.i;`. At what point does the value being stored in the first object cease to be an object?

Comment: Indeed. If you compile this into assembly using something like godbolt.org, the result is the same as "x.c = 0".

Comment: @IanAbbott `0 + x.i` is not an object. Neither is `(char)x.i`. Both are expressions whose values are computed from the value of an object.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That interpretation would render the passage meaningless. For any assignment `a = b;`, `b` is, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, converted from an lvalue to a value and no longer designates an object. By “read from another object,” the passage must be referring to objects used within the right operator of `=`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's a very good point. My guess is that the passage is supposed to apply when the RHS is an lvalue, but if so it should say so explicitly. An interesting implication is that `x.c = x.i;` differs semantically from `x.c = +x.i;`. I think you've found a flaw in the standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's also the type of thing that is likely to trip up maintainers. If they see `x.c = +x.i;` without comment, there is a chance they might remove the "useless" `+` operator, introducing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you've found a flaw in the standard. I think the intent is that `x.c = x.i;` has undefined behavior, but that passage (which has been in the standard since C90) does not correctly express that intent.

That wording applies to simple assignment. In a simple assignment, the LHS must be an lvalue, and the RHS is just an expression. If the RHS happens to be an lvalue, it undergoes *lvalue conversion* as described in 6.3.2.1p2. After lvalue conversion, it is no longer an lvalue.

It would be reasonable to say that an assignment that copies one object to another object has undefined behavior when the objects overlap (unless the overlap is exact and the objects have compatible type). But assignment does not operate on two objects; it operates on an object (the LHS) and a non-lvalue expression (the RHS).

The passage says that the value "is read from another object". That's ambiguous. Must name of the object be the entire RHS expression, or can it be just a subexpression? If the latter, then `x.c = x.i + 1;` would have undefined behavior, which in my opinion would be absurd.

As written, the conditions given in the quoted passage cannot occur.

If the passage were to be corrected, it should apply only when the RHS is an lvalue (before lvalue conversion), and would discuss overlap between the object designated by the LHS and the object designated by the RHS.

The specific case here, assigning overlapping small integer objects, is not likely to cause problems in practice, but we could construct cases that are more problematic. For example:

```
int main() {
    struct big {
        int array[1000];
    };

    struct big_wrapper {
        int n;
        struct big b;
    };


    union u {
        struct big x;
        struct big_wrapper y;
    };

    union u obj;
    obj.x = obj.y.b;
}
```

Here the assignment copies the value of one large object into another large object, where the two objects overlap but do not start at the same location. To implement this correctly, a compiler would have to detect the overlap and perhaps generate a call to `memmove()` or equivalent. And the overlap might not be directly visible if the assignment is performed via pointers. Making the behavior undefined allows compilers to generate efficient code for the non-overlapping cases.

The intent, I believe, is that this assignment also has undefined behavior but again the lvalue conversion means that that intent is not clearly expressed.

In my opinion, that passage should be updated to state that it applies when the RHS is an lvalue, and that the relevant objects are the LHS and the pre-conversion RHS.

Comment: I can see other potential intentions. For example, a big-endian C implementation on an eight-bit processor and `union { int a; struct { char b; int c; } s; } u;`, where 32-bit `int` does not require more than one-byte alignment. For `u.a = u.s.c + 3`, the C implementation might load the low byte of `u.s.c`, add 3, store the low byte of the sum into the low byte of `u.a`, then load the second-lowest byte of `u.s.c` to add the carry, but that byte has been altered since it is the low byte of `u.a`, so the operation goes awry.