# Is assigning a struct variable to itself (via pointer dereferencing) defined behaviour?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

If two pointers are pointing to the same struct variable, is it defined behaviour to assign one dereferenced pointer to the other?

```c
struct Struct {
    int member;
};

int main() {
    struct Struct s, *p1, *p2;
    s.member = 1234;
    p1 = p2 = &s;
    *p1 = *p2; // is this allowed?
}
```

I mainly ask because in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284033/copying-structure-in-c-with-assignment-instead-of-memcpy) a number of answers state that struct assignment is more or less equivalent to `memcpy`, and some compilers even generate a `memcpy` call for the assignment statement. However, `memcpy` is not defined when the memory locations overlap, which begs the question: is it defined for assignment?

This appears to be behaving as expected, but I would like to know if the C standard has anything to say about it. Is it necessary to add a simple check

```c
if (p1 != p2) *p1 = *p2;
```

or use `memmove` instead?

---

FYI, this came up when I was implementing my own slot map (as described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/33905)) in C. When removing an element from the container, the element at the end of the array gets copied to the deleted location to keep everything contiguous. In the case where the deleted element is at the end of the array, it will get copied to itself (not super important since that element is considered to be deleted, but got me curious anyway).

Comment: [Related question about assigning one member in a union to another.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077630/is-assigning-to-a-union-member-from-a-different-member-in-the-same-union-defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment is well defined. A corresponding call to `memcpy` would not be.

Here's what the standard says about simple assignment [N1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.15.6.1 paragraph 3):

> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object
> that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the
> overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or
> unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.

whereas for `memcpy` (7.24.2.1 paragraph 2):

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined.

So it's not correct that struct assignment is equivalent to `memcpy`, though the "more or less" qualification is appropriate. For one thing, as we see here, `memcpy` between exactly overlapping objects is undefined, while assignment is well defined. For another, `memcpy` preserves the values of any padding bytes (gaps between members or after the last one), while assignment is not guaranteed to do so. Assignment *could* be implemented by copying each member rather than by copying the entire structure.

That being said, an implementation could implement assignment and `memcpy` in exactly the same way. The fact that some cases have undefined behavior means that an implementation is free to do anything convenient.

Comment: Re “Assignment *could* be implemented by copying each member rather than by copying the entire structure”: Yes, but that would not explain why `*p1 = *p2;` might change the padding in this case, since copying each member (exactly its bytes) would not change the padding bytes. However, an implementation could implement the assignment by, say, reading a `char` member with a load-and-zero-extend byte instruction and then using a store-word instruction to write over the member and the padding that follows it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil gcc could do better: https://godbolt.org/z/6T4fo8eEd

Comment: @gulpr: Not the point. It is not about what is best or what any particular compiler does. The question is whether the behavior is defined, and the point raised in this answer is that the resulting padding bytes are not specified.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cG9ohxsK1 - undefined?

Comment: @EricPostpischil it was not an answer to the question. The test was inspired by your comment

Answer (score 2):

```
*p1 = *p2; // is this allowed?
```

Yes, it is OK and very efficient. `struct`s and `union`s are assignable and the whole structure or union is being copied.

> Is it necessary to add a simple check
>
> ```
> if (p1 != p2) *p1 = *p2;
> ```

no, it is not needed, but the assignment can be costly (imagine a very large struct). If you do not check and do not want to use the assignment you should use `memmove` function instead of `memcpy`

```
typedef struct
{
    double a[1000];
}s_t;


void foo(s_t *a, const s_t *b)
{
    *a = *b;
}
```

It will translate into

```
foo:
        mov     ecx, 1000
        rep movsq
        ret
```

Adding a check will prevent long operation from happening.